# $\operatorname {Ext}$ vanishing and finitely generated reflexive modules over regular local rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors, regular-rings

Let $M$ be a finitely generated reflexive module over a regular local ring $(R,\mathfrak m,k)$ such that $\operatorname {Ext}^1_R( \operatorname {Hom}_R(M,M),R)=0$. Then how to show that $M$ is a free $R$-module ?

Here reflexive means $\operatorname {Hom}_R(\operatorname {Hom}_R(M,R),R)\cong M$ .

My try: since we're in a regular local ring, so $pd(M)+depth M=depth R=\dim R$. So to show $M$ is free, it is enough to show $depth(M)\ge depth(R)$. Also, since our module is finitely generated over a Noetherian local ring, 
so $M$ is free if and only if $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(M,k)=0$. Unfortunatelyy I don't know how to show any of these.

Please help.

Comment: Do you know if $\text{Ext}^{i}(\text{Hom}(M,M),R)=0$ for all $i\geq1$?

Comment: @Zeek: I do not ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is just Theorem 2.1 in https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01229753